# How to build a gcc compiler on Linux that builds both 32-bit and 64-bit code

Tags: linux, gcc, ubuntu-16.04

I followed the directions in the following URL to build a gcc compiler for Linux:

https://solarianprogrammer.com/2016/10/07/building-gcc-ubuntu-linux/

The resulting compiler builds 64-bit code with no problems.

However, when I try to build 32-bit code (by specifying the -m32 compiler option), I get errors.

Here are the errors that I get:

1. cannot find -lstdc++
2. cannot find -lgcc_s
3. skipping incompatible libgcc.a when searching foor -lgcc
4. cannot find -lgcc

Obviously, when I built the compiler, I did something wrong - can anyone tell me what I did wrong and how I can rebuild the compiler to build both 32-bit and 64-bit code.

Comment: All these are complaints that it can't find 32-bit versions of libraries. You probably need to build those as well as build the compiler itself.

Comment: This is the config line from the link: ../gcc-8.1.0/configure -v --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr/local/gcc-8.1 --enable-checking=release --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran --disable-multilib --program-suffix=-8.1

Comment: That line specifies x86_64 for host, build, and target.  Does that mean I have to build a separate compiler that can build 32-bit code?  Or if I just build the 32 libraries and repeat the process of building the compiler itself, will that suffice for building 64-bit and 32-bit binaries?

Comment: `--disable-multilib` explicitly disables 32-bit support...

Comment: Ok, let me try your suggestion.

Comment: Thank you so much - it worked!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You at least need to configure with `--with-multilib-list=m32,m64` on the configure command line.<sup>1</sup>  You definitely need to *not* configure with `--disable-multilib`.  You may also need to build&install additional versions of other libraries.

In general, searching the documentation for 'multilib' will show you all the places where it talks about building or using gcc with multiple target ABIs.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>This is the default on at least some versions of gcc. You could also add `mx32` if you want to experiment with that.</sub>